# Adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc causes dependency issues

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Using Abp 3.8.2, building a method within my Abp.Application project that has to be a GET.  The documentation says use [HttpGet] however, doing so requires me to add Microsoft.AspnetCore.Mvc to the project.

As soon as I go that, my build starts getting

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

I'm using the suggested import, but thinking Abp wants something different?

It's still a pretty basic application and I haven't included anything else that would be causing collisions:
[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: As a follow up, if I add Microsoft.AspNetCore.All to the entire Abp solution, the warning goes away.   Seems like I'm taking a sledgehammer to the problem, but I've been poking around for days removing and adding packages back in to determine where the dependency collision is.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

By default, all methods are created as a POST. We can change this behavior **WithVerb Method**

We can use **WithVerb** for a method like this:

```cs
Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApi().DynamicApiControllerBuilder
    .For<ITaskAppService>("tasksystem/task")
    .ForMethod("GetTasks").WithVerb(HttpVerb.Get)
    .Build();
```

See https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dynamic-Web-API#http-verbs

---

Also, instead of declaring the HTTP attributes for every method, you can use the WithConventionalVerbs method as shown below:

```
Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApi().DynamicApiControllerBuilder
    .ForAll<IApplicationService>(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SimpleTaskSystemApplicationModule)), "tasksystem")
    .WithConventionalVerbs()
    .Build();
```

Comment: I know we can declare as Get using WithVerb etc, but prefer (as most do I suspect) to simply annotate the rare methods that don't follow convention.  The documentaiton says it's ok to use the annotations, and I am using them fine in fact.  The only problem is that unless I include AspDotNetCore.All NuGet package, I get a version mismatch on the mentioned assembly.  I suspect there is some old dependency in the project that is not up to date.